# C - Concurrency issue with threads, arguments are being printed twice

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I wrote this program that's supposed create a new thread in every iteration of the main loop and have it print the iteration variable. Eg. in the first iteration, a new thread is made and it should print "arg: 0", next iteration prints "arg: 1", etc.

As you can see in the screenshot below, arg 3 & 7 are being printed twice, while it should only print once. Now it works if I add sleep(1) to every iteration, so it's some kind of concurrency issue. Note that the result is completely random every time, it's not just 3 and 7 every time.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <pthread.h>

static void * mutex_thread(void * arg);
int threads_amt = 10;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t threads[threads_amt];

    // Create threads.
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_amt; i++) 
    {
        printf ("Starting thread [%d]...\n", i);

        // Create thread.
        pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, mutex_thread, &i);

        // IT WORKS IF I ENABLE sleep(1).
        //sleep (1);

        printf ("Thread created.\n\n");
    }

    // Join threads.
    printf("Joining threads...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < threads_amt; i++) 
    {
        pthread_join (threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return (0);
}

static void * mutex_thread(void * arg) 
{
    // Lock mutex.
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);

    // Print arg.
        int *number = (int*)arg;
        printf("arg: %d\n", *number);

    // Unlock mutex.
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);

    return (NULL);
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: What happens if you print `arg`, in addition to `*arg`, from each thread?

Comment: Is `printf` thread-safe?

Comment: Give `pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, mutex_thread, &i);` a pointer to  own copy of `i` rather than a pointer to the shared variable?

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't think that's possible, arg is a pointer so it would just print the memory allocation number.

Comment: @nwp: For any recent implementation `printf()` shall be thread safe, yes.

Comment: @chux I tried adding "int i_copy = i;" under "Starting thread..." and then passing i_copy as parameter to pthread_create, but the same thing happens.

Comment: That is a copy of `i`, not a unique copy per thread.  IOWs, its "own" copy.

Comment: @chux How would I make a unique copy per thread? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question... I'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: `int xx[threads_amt]; for(int i = 0; i < threads_amt; i++)  { xx[i] = i; 
        pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, mutex_thread, &xx[i]); ...` may work.  See [@usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512346/2410359)

Comment: @chux Thank you, that seems to work. Is there any way to do this without an array?

Comment: Sure, do not `i++` until the thread is done reading `i`.  But that is more complicated - IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [*data race*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) - because you are passing the same address (of variable `i`) to *all* the threads.

Pass a different address (for example use an array or use a `malloc'ed value) to each thread.

Comment: Or do `pthread_create(..., (void*)(intptr_t) i));` And inside the tread function just do `printf("arg: %d\n", (int)(intptr_t) arg);`.

Comment: @alk That relies on successfully round tripping `int --> intptr_t --> void *--> intptr_t --> int`.  Something not specified by C to work.  Arbitrary integer values to not always convert well to a pointer.

Comment: @chux:  Fair enough. I should have added that the `int` in question needs to be between `INTPTR_MIN` and `INTPTR_MAX`.

Comment: @alk Although `int --> intptr_t --> int` may fail, it is the `some_arbitrary_int --> void *` that is UB.

Comment: @usr This is it. Thank you!

Comment: @chux: I wasn't talking about "*`some_arbitrary_int`*", but about `intptr_t` which is guaranteed to convert to/from any `void`-pointer value (C11: 7.20.1.4/1).

Comment: @alk the "`intptr_t` which is guaranteed to convert **to**" part only applies if the `intptr_t` was derived from a prior `void* --> intptr_t` and not from some_arbitrary_int_or_intptr_t.

Comment: @chux: I think I just got your point. It's the direction of conversion you are referring to, right?

Comment: @alk Yes.  .........  round tripping `void * --> intptr_t --> void *` is good, yet round trip code cannot start in the middle.